# Did Hamas or the Islamic Jihad ever took blame for rocket misfires?

Tags: terrorism, hamas

The recent Gaza hospital blast has caused significant loss of life.
Estimates range between 471-500 (Gaza HM) and 100-300 (US intelligence) people killed. ([AP](https://apnews.com/article/israel-hamas-war-gaza-health-ministry-health-death-toll-59470820308b31f1faf73c703400b033)), and there still an ongoing investigation underway on the subject:

> Israel faces blame from regional allies over Gaza hospital deaths  ([The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/oct/18/israel-faces-blame-from-regional-allies-over-gaza-hospital-deaths))

and

> “It appears the result of an errant rocket fired by a terrorist
> group,” the U.S. president says. ([NBC](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/live-blog/israel-hamas-war-live-updates-rcna120978))

and

> There is little doubt that the destruction of the al-Ahli Arab Hospital is a war crime, no matter who is ultimately responsible. ([Al Jazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/opinions/2023/10/26/the-icc-should-urgently-investigate-what-happened-at-al-ahli-arab-hospital))

It seems a significant amount of the weaponry and rockets fired from Gaza are homemade ([CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/10/13/middleeast/hamas-weapons-invs/index.html#:%7E:text=Hamas%20produces%20the%20vast%20majority,makeshift%20rockets%20is%20less%20known.))
so there may be a risk they wont reach their indented targets, but explode on Gazan territory.
Israeli news also reported in September a 'premature explosion':

> 6 killed in Gaza border blast during rioting, apparently while
> planting bomb ([Times of Israel](https://www.timesofisrael.com/4-killed-in-gaza-border-blast-during-rioting-apparently-while-planting-bomb/))

and

> according to the IDF one in five Gaza rockets misfires, kills
> Palestinians ([jpost](https://www.jpost.com/middle-east/article-769509))

In the recent conflict, according to Israel, in two weeks [7000 rockets](https://apnews.com/article/iron-dome-missile-defense-israel-palestinians-rockets-hamas-f57508d0e53945d1071d4582fcdae8d2) were fired from the Gaza strip.

Considering Gaza doesn't have an [Iron Dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Dome), 1/5 rockets misfiring can cause quite a lot of damage, even if Israel doesn't fire back (which they do).

I am curious, **if** it was a Jihad misfire, how likely that they'd admit it?

**So did organizations like the Hamas or the Islamic Jihad ever took blame for rocket misfires or homemade explosives going off in their own populated areas?**

Comment: I vaguely recall hearing in some of the TV coverage the PIJ being quoted as saying something like "we admitted errors before, but we never made one of this magnitude". Don't have pointer. And IDK how often they admitted errors in reality.

Comment: @Fizz i managed to find this https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-66806141 but in this case the whole thing was broadcasted from start to end, so not sure if it counts

Comment: From all the damage done to that Gaza hospital, the rocket was quite powerful. I am surprised that Hamas was able to build a rocket with such a powerful warhead.

Comment: @user57467 makes you wonder what would happen if the israelis didnt have the iron dome

Comment: @user57467: Hamas has some of these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaibar-1 (300mm rockets) derivatives of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weishi_rockets Although that's probably not what hit the hospital yard, given the minimal damage done to the actual buildings. 300mm rockets are what Russia used to bombard Kharkiv with, albeit mostly with cluster warheads. https://edition.cnn.com/2022/05/12/world/russia-general-ukraine-syria-cluster-bombs-intl-cmd/index.html

Comment: Correction: the missile exploded in a *parking lot*, not a *hospital*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that denying responsibility (and thus not admitting errors) might be easier or more difficult to do depending on the circumstances.

If you mislaunch some homebrews in the midst of a non-violent phase, when the IDF isn't operating around Gaza, then you will have a harder time claiming it was Israel rather than your own screwup.

If however, the situation is like right now, with so much IDF ordnance being fired at Gaza, it is fairly trivial to claim it wasn't you, but rather Israel.  And, given the alleged magnitude of casualties, there is a much larger incentive to do so.

Bottom line:  that Hamas or Islamic Jihad admitted errors in the past, especially on smaller accidents, would give no real insight on whether they are being truthful or not in their denials in the case of *this* hospital event.

Comment: Indeed, and this is hardly particular from Hamas, or terrorist organizations in general. In the 9/6 [market massacre](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/09/18/world/europe/ukraine-missile-kostiantynivka-market.html) incident, Zelensky was quick to accuse Russia of war crimes. While later investigations determined it was an ukrainian anti-aircraft missile, the ukrainian officials remained silent. I haven't heard of any of them acknowledging the error. Israel has never acknowledged any wrongdoing that wasn't filmed, either, and sometimes not even those.